# Limits and derivatives - limit of a trigonometric function

Tags: limits

**Question:**

> Find the limit of: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^9x}{x}.$$

Well using the L-Hopital's Rule, I can write:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^9x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{9\cos^8x}{1}.$$

This will simplify to give the answer as 9. Is this the correct answer? (As the answer key gave the answer as $\pi\over180$)

Comment: The correct answer is $0$. Check your derivative.

Comment: Roughly $\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$. So you should expect $x^8$.

Comment: How about writing the limit as $sin^8x\frac{sinx}{x}$? The latter term is a standard limit.

Comment: It will sound like my usual rant, but why on Earth would your first reflex be to use L'Hopital's on this? Knowing that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1$, you can conclude.

Comment: But we will get $0\over0$ form on this @ClementC.

Comment: @Gummybears The limit Clement is referring to, is a Standard limit. It is 1 and does not have to proven again and again. That's why he said, "you can conclude" I was hinting at the work of Kobe

Comment: @imranfat I don't get it. I know the standard limit. But how can I apply it here?

Comment: $\frac{\sin^9 x}{x} = \frac{\sin^9 x}{x^9}\cdot x^8 = \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^9\cdot x^8$, for instance.

Comment: See Kobe's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's incorrect. After applying L'hospital's rule, you should have $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{9\sin^8 x\cos x}{1}$. Note that you can solve this without L'hospital's rule by noting writing

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^9 x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \sin^8 x = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0} \sin^8 x = 1 \cdot 0 = 0.$$

Comment: Oops. Yes I differentiated incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

A way to go is recalling that, as $x$ is near $0$,
$$
\sin x = x +\mathcal{O}(x^3)
$$ leading to
$$
\frac{\sin^9 x}{x}=\frac{x^9 +\mathcal{O}(x^{10})}{x}=x^8+\mathcal{O}(x^{9})
$$ giving $0$ as the desired limit.